# Laravel - message bag not visible

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 7.0.

In my app/Exceptions/Handler.php method "render". I needed create condition for "PostTooLargeException".

Response is different if request come from ajax or not.

The problem is if request is not ajax. I'm trying to return back with some error message but anything what I want to return in function "with()" or "withErrors()" it's not exist in blade views.

What is wrong, why it happens?

My code:

```
if ($exception instanceof PostTooLargeException) {

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response(['message' => "The file you are trying to send is too large "], 422);
    } {
        $errors = new MessageBag();
        $errors->add('error', 'test');
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors);
    }
}
```

Blade:

```
@if($errors->any())
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
                 @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                       <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                 @endforeach
          </ul>
      </div>
 @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

without `MessageBag` you can achieve that by passing array to `withErrors`

```
 return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error' => "test"]);
```

Comment: This way I tested as well. And without success.

Comment: @Klick any erorr  with this code ?. i have tested same code with your mentioned blade code so it works well in laravel 8  and able to see error message. try clearing cache

Comment: I did. I have no clue what can be wrong. I didn't write this project from the scratch. So maybe previews developers change something  in settings? Is it possible? If yes where should I looking for it?

Comment: @Klick okay. Difficult to guess  but try dd(($errors->all()) and in view and see what you get

Comment: I did it as well. And it always empty.

Comment: @Klick let me try again  and inform you back if i found any solution and may i know where is you code first of all ? is it in controller ?

Comment: I wrote it on top in my post. The code is in: "app/Exceptions/Handler.php" in "render" method.

Comment: @Klick sorry its my mistake .i understood wrongly.let me check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235095/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-klick).

Comment: @Klick 
can you show full code. i have verified it works .first make sure whether it goes inside of that exception